# Make a function to refresh a data on page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function that, when called, will refresh data on a page (change the value on screen to the new value of the variable).

I thought that this could do it:

```
function refreshData(data) {
document.getElementById("data").innerhtml = data;
}
```

And then I would simply call it like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
time -= 1;
refreshData(time);
},1000);
```

But I get the following error code in my console when I test it (and the countdown freezes):

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

I'm 100% sure that it's not a dumb HTML error because when I use the following code I have no problem:

```
 document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;
```

So the actual question is: How could I fix this and (for general knowledge) why did my previous code fail?

Comment: What is this? document.getElementById("data")

Comment: `document.getElementById("data") = data;` should be `document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data`;

Comment: Thanks that was a dumb mistake... but I now get a new error code :(

Comment: what does your data look like and what type of element is the data element?

Comment: @LearningJS You are missing an element with `[id="data"]` on your HTML DOM.

Comment: I'm trying to make an incremental game (to get a little better in js) http://etudecsb.com/lifeclicker/ now I'm trying to make a function that will save some time (I'll just have to call the function instead of the long way) and since i'll have to do that with a lot of different elements I want the function to be versatile and not just useful for a specific element.

Comment: @R Lam there is no element with data as an id... the point is that when I call the function, where is data will be the id of the element (in the current situation the element's id is time) I want to change and the name variable I want to change it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns you the `element`. Its **invalid** to set `data` directly to the element rather than to its attribute and you need to set the value to it as its `innerHTML`. That is why you were getting **`"ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side"`** on your First Statement. So use

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=data
```

Here is **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0n1zn5dn/1/)**

Comment: Thanks helps a lot, but now I get a new error code... TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: That's because that `element` isn't present in `DOM`.. Make sure you have that `element` in `html`

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("data") = data;
```

this is an invalid assignment, `getElementById()` returns a DOM element.

using `document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;` works because now your setting `time` to `innerHTML` of the result of `getElementById()`.

Comment: so if I understand, there's no way to make the function get a different Id each time I call it.